# How to ignore a maven pom.xml sub-module from parent clean install in intelliji

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I work with intelliji and I have a parent module containing several sub-modules each having a pom.xml. I try to ignore a child sub-module from a clean install of the parent, right clicking on the child project then selecting Maven -> ignore Projects, but I have still an error on this child project telling me that the clean install on parent still takes into account this child project

Answer (score 1):

I found another way to exclude a module. In the run/debug configuration, I execute

```
clean install -pl !module
```

The discussion is closed